# Native Mobile Controls for Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I spoofed the user agent in Chrome to be a mobile device and was presented with this great mobile UI when I visited maps.google.com:

[image: Awesome Mobile UI for Google Maps]

Is this a native part of the Google Maps API and thus could used in a mobile web app?  If so, how would one configure their Google Map to display this mobile UI?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That UI is specific to maps.google.com. The api does however expose the necessary interfaces to develop your own version, but does not have the same controls built in.